# Is it possible to set amp-accordion expanded attribute by media size?

Tags: amp-html

I have an AMP page with a bunch of content sections. I would like to display them in an amp-accordion for mobile view only.

The approach I've taken is:

- put sections into an amp-accordion element
- add "expanded" attribute to all sections
- use media queries to hide section headings for desktop view

The above allows the page to look "normal" on desktop i.e. when the page loads all sections are expanded and you can't see that they are part of an accordion. On mobile, the section headings are visible, allowing the various sections to be opened or closed by the user.

The only problem is, on mobile view, I would like all sections to be closed when the page loads. This is the default behaviour and appears to be controlled by adding or removing the "expanded" attribute to each section. Unfortunately you can't manipulate element attributes with CSS. Is there another method I could use for this? I looked briefly at amp-bind but can't see that that could be triggered by the media size either.